# Padding in a structure of floats

Tags: c++, memory-alignment

Consider this code:

```
struct Foo {
  float a, b;
};

void bar(float array[2]) {
  ... // read array[0] and array[1]
}

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  bar(&foo.a);
}
```

Is this code safe? It is to say, is `bar` accessing `foo.a` and `foo.b` always? It doesn't seem safe to me since padding may be happening, but I don't know if we can assume padding is 0 since `a` and `b` are `float`.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour. If you value the friendship and respect of your colleagues, avoid.

Comment: Could you point me to some doc/standard?

Comment: https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard

Comment: Probably section 9.2.13 from the standard discourages this.

Answer (score 1):

It is more or less safe because there are no technical reasons for floats in a struct be aligned differently than in an array. But such code is hard to understand: such tricks with using the same memory as different types force you to think much and distract from essential things in code. And it is really hardly ever needed to do them. So it is best to avoid such tricks.

If I'm not mistaken there is no official guarantee that such code will work, so if you want to be absolutely safe and you need such code, then you can add a static_assert:

```
static_assert(offsetof(Foo, b) - offsetof(Foo, a) == sizeof(float));
```

Comment: There is no need to check a's offset because ChronoTrigger invokes bar with a's address, not a struct's address.